# Technology vs. Technologies as a chapter name?

Tags: grammar

What would the correct name be for a chapter in my thesis where I describe (multiple) software and programs? Technology or technologies? [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience (UK IT industry), either would be correct and fine, but "technologies" is newer in common usage.  It may be that for that reason, "technologies" may still sound slightly pretentious or perhaps "management-speak" to some ears.

Comment: To me "technology" sounds better I just wasnt sure it is correct. So "technology" it is!